# Setting build properties in Android Gradle via Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

How do you tell Jenkins to set a property inside `gradle.properties` in an Android project? I've figured out how to get the properties from Gradle into Jenkins (by using the *EnvInject plugin* and simply entering `gradle.properties` into the property file field) but I also want the build number that is managed by Jenkins to be injected into the build artifact.

I also want to set the filename of the resulting artifact which, I think, needs to be injected by using `archivesBaseName`. But that property isn't part of `gradle.properties` so I wonder how do I access it?

So far I've only found solutions that change the `build.gradle` file (or other gradle scripts) in the Android project itself. But that's not what I want to do because that would make the Android code base rely on Jenkins.

Instead I want Jenkins to provide the build number and artifact file name to the Android project before it compiles the code.

The server runs on a Mac. Does anyone have a solution for this? Any shell/Groovy script that does the job would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We are just wrinting a file version.properties, which is generated by jenkins "echo "VERSION_CODE=${BUILD_NUBMER}" > version.properies" script.

Then gradle script imports it as following:

```
// Version code is loaded from a properties file
        def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

            def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()

            versionCode code
        }
        else {
            throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
        }

        buildConfigField "String", " some _VERSION", "\"${getVersionString()}\""
    }
```